# can i make a ajax post from a salesforce button

Tags: javascript, button

I have a button on salesforce record page which calls a url with parameters from a post call is made . Is there a way i can make post call from salesforce button directly?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Are you making an ajax call outside SF to an external endpoint or you want to call an internal VF page or something?

Comment: You can make a POST call from a JavaScript button - here is an [example for a different purpose](http://force201.wordpress.com/2014/07/23/how-to-pass-a-large-number-of-selections-from-a-standard-list-view-to-a-visualforce-page/).

Comment: @Bachovski its an ajax call to external endpoint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a POST call from a JavaScript button e.g.:

```
var ids = {!GETRECORDIDS($ObjectType.Contact)};
if (ids.length) {
    var form = document.createElement("form");
    form.setAttribute("method", "POST");
    form.setAttribute("action", "https://c.na15.visual.force.com/apex/Target");
    var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
    hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
    hiddenField.setAttribute("name", "ids");
    hiddenField.setAttribute("value", ids.join(','));
    form.appendChild(hiddenField);
    document.body.appendChild(form);
    form.submit();
} else {
    alert('Select one or more Contacts');
}
```

See [How to pass a large number of selections from a standard list view to a Visualforce page](http://force201.wordpress.com/2014/07/23/how-to-pass-a-large-number-of-selections-from-a-standard-list-view-to-a-visualforce-page/) for more information about this example.